# @URL.Action links not clickable within a bootstrap dropdown menu

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4, navbar

I am using the latest bootstrap and jQuery versions and I've created a navbar which links to different actions within the controllers.

The problem I've got is that when you try using one of the links within `<li class="nav-item dropdown">` it doesn't recognise that you've clicked on it. It's strange as when you look through developer tools you can see the links and these work, it just seems your unable to reach them for some reason.

I've gone through many different pages trying this in a different format & making sure the scripts are in the right order but nothing that's fixed the other problems seem to be working.

I'm sure this will probably be something simple and hopefully, someone can provide some insight into what I'm doing wrong :)

**NavBar HTML**

```
<ul class="wraplist" style="height: auto;">
            <li><a href="@Url.Action("CostCentres", "Home")"><span class="sidebar-icon"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i></span> <span class="menu-title">Cost Centres</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="@Url.Action("Applications", "Home")"><span class="sidebar-icon"><i class="fa fa-bullseye"></i></span> <span class="menu-title">Applications</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="@Url.Action("Employees", "Home")"><span class="sidebar-icon"><i class="fa fa-users"></i></span> <span class="menu-title">Employees</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "SOD")"><span class="sidebar-icon"><i class="fa fa-th-list"></i></span> <span class="menu-title">Manage SOD's</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="@Url.Action("Conflicts", "SOD")"><span class="sidebar-icon"><i class="fas fa-desktop"></i></span> <span class="menu-title">Conflicts Dashboard</span></a></li>

            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown" id="conflictsdropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style="padding:0 0 0 5px;">
                    <span class="sidebar-icon">
                        <i class="fas fa-user-secret"></i>
                    </span>
                    <span class="menu-title" style="padding-left:0;">Manage Conflicts</span>
                </a>
                <ul class="nav-item dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="conflictsdropdown" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="@Url.Action("ManageConflictsAll", "SOD")">All</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="@Url.Action("ManageConflictsEscalations", "SOD")">Escalations</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Functions")"><span class="sidebar-icon"><i class="fa fa-align-justify"></i></span> <span class="menu-title">Manage Functions</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="@Url.Action("TechnicalAccounts", "Home")"><span class="sidebar-icon"><i class="fa fa-suitcase"></i></span> <span class="menu-title">Technical Accounts</span></a></li>
        </ul>
```

**Script Order**

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

**Dev Tools** 
[Google Dev Tools Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/edL9k.png)

**Rendered NavBar**
[Navbar showing selected item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQRaN.png)

Comment: Will you be able to make a fiddle, I can't seem to replicate it.

Comment: Sure thing, I've created a fiddle here: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/m7jzwf6s/) 
it although I've copied everything across. The dropdown doesn't work at all in the fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your markup for the dropdown is incorrect. Please look at the markup on the [Bootstrap docs here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/#using-dropdowns) for dropdowns in navs. You have put the `data-toggle="dropdown"` on the wrong element and your dropdown/nav-link classes are all messed up.

Also you are init the dropdown in javascript like this: `$(".dropdown").dropdown();` and you have the dropdown class on the parent of the actually dropdown and you put `data-toggle="dropdown"` on your menu not the toggle. Adding `data-toggle="dropdown"` is all that is needed (on the correct element) then you don't have to init it javascript. do one or the other... not both!

**Incorrect:**

```
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown" id="conflictsdropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style="padding:0 0 0 5px;">
            <span class="sidebar-icon">
              <i class="fas fa-user-secret"></i>
            </span>
            <span class="menu-title" style="padding-left:0;">Manage Conflicts</span>
          </a>
          <ul class="nav-item dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="conflictsdropdown" data-toggle="dropdown">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="@Url.Action(" ManageConflictsAll", "SOD" )">All</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="@Url.Action(" ManageConflictsEscalations", "SOD" )">Escalations</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".dropdown").dropdown(); //not needed when data-toggle="dropdown" is present
});
```

**Correct:**

```
 <li class="nav-item dropdown">
      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><span class="sidebar-icon">
          <i class="fas fa-user-secret"></i>
        </span>
        <span class="menu-title" style="padding-left:0;">Manage Conflicts</span></a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="https://www.google.com">All</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="@Url.Action(" ManageConflictsEscalations", "SOD" )">Escalations</a>
      </div>
    </li>
```

Here is a example that has your wrong "Manage Conflicts" nav item and then below it is the correct markup for "Manage Conflicts" nav item with a working link in the dropdown.

```js
$('ul.nav li.dropdown').hover(function() {
  $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(100).fadeIn(500);
}, function() {
  $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(100).fadeOut(500);
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".dropdown .dropdown").dropdown(); //Only used to demo problem menu item. selector changed to ".dropdown .dropdown" so it wouldn't mess up the correct dropdown
});
```

```css
.page-sidebar {
  height: auto;
  width: 260px;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 rgba(33, 33, 33, .2);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 rgba(33, 33, 33, .2);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 rgba(33, 33, 33, .2);
  -o-box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 rgba(33, 33, 33, .2);
  -ms-box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 rgba(33, 33, 33, .2);
  min-height: 100%;
}

.page-sidebar.fixedscroll {
  position: fixed;
}

.page-sidebar.collapseit {
  width: 60px;
  margin-left: 0px !important;
  z-index: 99;
}

.page-sidebar .profile-info {
  background: transparent;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  display: flex;
}

.page-sidebar .profile-image {
  padding-right: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.profile-info .profile-image img {
  height: 65px;
  width: 65px;
  float: right;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  position: relative;
}

.short-profile img {
  height: 45px !important;
  width: 45px !important;
  left: 2px !important;
}

.short-profile .profile-details {
  display: none;
}

.profile-info .profile-details h3 {
  margin: 19px 0px 6px 14px;
}

.profile-info .profile-details .profile-title {
  color: rgba(174, 178, 183, 1.0);
  font-size: 13px;
  margin: 0px 0px 6px 14px;
}

#main-menu-wrapper ul {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

#main-menu-wrapper .menusection {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 40px;
  padding-left: 24px;
  margin: 10px 0 0px 0;
  color: #9e9e9e;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.profile-info .profile-details h3 a {
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #757575;
  font-size: 19px;
  line-height: 23px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#main-menu-wrapper li a {
  display: block;
  line-height: 42px;
  min-height: 42px;
  height: auto;
  color: #424242;
  text-decoration: none;
  /*    padding: 14px 0px;*/
  padding-left: 5px;
  clear: both;
  border-left: 4px solid transparent;
  white-space: nowrap;
  /*    font-size: 18px;*/
}

#main-menu-wrapper .fa {
  font-size: 14px;
}

#main-menu-wrapper li a i {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 34px;
  line-height: 34px;
  text-align: center;
  top: 0px;
  position: relative;
}

#main-menu-wrapper li a:hover {
  background-color: rgba(33, 33, 33, 0.1);
  border-left: 4px solid #35395c;
}

#main-content {
  margin-left: 260px;
  display: block;
}

#main-content.sidebar_shift {
  margin-left: 60px;
  margin-right: 0px;
}

.main-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px 15px 0 15px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="page-sidebar expandit">
  <div class="sidebar-inner" id="main-menu-wrapper">
    <div class="profile-info row ">
      <div class="profile-image ">
        <a href="ui-profile.html">
          <img alt="" src="~/Images/panda.jpg" class="img-circle img-inline img-responsive img-circle">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <ul class="wraplist" style="height: auto;">
      <li><a href="@Url.Action(" CostCentres ", "Home " )"><span class="sidebar-icon"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i></span> <span class="menu-title">Cost Centres</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="@Url.Action(" Applications ", "Home " )"><span class="sidebar-icon"><i class="fa fa-bullseye"></i></span> <span class="menu-title">Applications</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="@Url.Action(" Employees ", "Home " )"><span class="sidebar-icon"><i class="fa fa-users"></i></span> <span class="menu-title">Employees</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="@Url.Action(" Index ", "SOD " )"><span class="sidebar-icon"><i class="fa fa-th-list"></i></span> <span class="menu-title">Manage SOD's</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="@Url.Action(" Conflicts ", "SOD " )"><span class="sidebar-icon"><i class="fas fa-desktop"></i></span> <span class="menu-title">Conflicts Dashboard</span></a></li>

      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown" id="conflictsdropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style="padding:0 0 0 5px;">
          <span class="sidebar-icon">
              <i class="fas fa-user-secret"></i>
            </span>
          <span class="menu-title" style="padding-left:0;">Manage Conflicts</span>
        </a>
        <ul class="nav-item dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="conflictsdropdown" data-toggle="dropdown">
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="@Url.Action(" ManageConflictsAll ", "SOD " )">All</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="@Url.Action(" ManageConflictsEscalations ", "SOD " )">Escalations</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><span class="sidebar-icon">
              <i class="fas fa-user-secret"></i>
            </span>
            <span class="menu-title" style="padding-left:0;">Manage Conflicts</span></a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="https://www.google.com">All</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="@Url.Action(" ManageConflictsEscalations ", "SOD " )">Escalations</a>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li><a href="@Url.Action(" Index ", "Functions " )"><span class="sidebar-icon"><i class="fa fa-align-justify"></i></span> <span class="menu-title">Manage Functions</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="@Url.Action(" TechnicalAccounts ", "Home " )"><span class="sidebar-icon"><i class="fa fa-suitcase"></i></span> <span class="menu-title">Technical Accounts</span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```